# Creating javadoc only for latest changes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am working with `IntelliJ IDEA 11` on a project. I am generating `javadoc` with the `maven-javadoc-plugin`, but then I can only create the javadoc for the whole project.

Is there a way that I can create `javadoc` only for the latest files that were changed, respectively the files of the last commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achieve what I wanted by using the Doclet API.
What I basically did was iterating through my project files and reading the revision from the code comments. Then I used Doclet to create javadoc for each single file with matching revision.